# Swimmers' favouritism towards letters!

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, letters, sports

***This puzzle is about five professional male swimmers***

---

> 1. In 2004, after swimming for 200 m and 400 m separately, ***Michael Phelps*** started disliking **double E** but liked the letter **I**. He then started reading in a **DIMLY** lit room.

---

> 2. In 2000, after swimming for 400 m, ***Ian Thorpe*** started disliking **triple E** but liked the city of **RIO**. He then began taking interest in **FLORISTRY**.

---

> 3. In 1972, after swimming for 200 m and 400 m separately, ***Mark Spitz*** started disliking **BRUT** wine but liked the remaining letters. He then became a **LEFTY**.

---

> 4. In 2008, after swimming for 200 m, __________ started liking every letter along with liking Al **GORE** as well. He then began a career in **STOCKBROKERAGE**.

---

> 5. In 2016, after swimming for 100 m, __________ started disliking **double REST** but liked the letter **Z**. He then moved to a Croatian town named **ZABOK**.

---

***What are the names of the fourth and fifth swimmers?***

P.S.

> I had originally included a different word instead of **GORE** in number 4 which would have affected the final word in that paragraph. I have corrected it after @Stiv pointed it out. Thanks to him.

Comment: Is there a surplus G in #4? You could easily correct this by him liking GORE instead...

Comment: @Stiv You're absolutely right. Thanks for bringing to my notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The swimmers are:

> [Ryan Lochte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swimming_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_200_metre_backstroke) and [Adam Peaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swimming_at_the_2016_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_100_metre_breaststroke).

How to identify them:

> We can work backwards from the bold, all-caps word at the end. It must be modified by removing the letters the swimmer likes and by adding the letters he dislikes. The resulting set of letters can then be anagrammed to a swimming stroke. The athlete in question has won the Olympic swimming competition in the given year and over the given distance for that stroke:
>
>   DIMLY − I + EE = Medley
>   FLORISTRY − RIO + EEE = Freestyle
>   LEFTY + BRUTE = Butterfly
>   STOCKBROKERAGE − GORE = Backstroke
>   ZABOK − Z + REST + REST = Breaststroke.